# Upload files WITHOUT ssh keypair to ec2 instance using boto3 SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, boto3, aws-ssm

The SSM client for boto3 uses AWS config settings as an authentication mechanism, allowing a python program to run commands on a remote ec2 instance.

I would like to upload files to the ec2 instance. Previous SO questions ([How to scp to ec2 instance via ssm agent using boto3 and send file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017649/how-to-scp-to-ec2-instance-via-ssm-agent-using-boto3-and-send-file)) indicate that this is possible over ssh.

Is it possible to upload files to the instance using SSM without an SSH keypair?

One way to do this may be something like:

```py
with open('path/to/file', r) as f:
  contents = f.read()

resp = boto3('ssm').send_command(
  InstanceIds=[...],
  Commands=[f'echo "{contents}" > file.txt']
)
```

but this seems very fragile.

Context: I am building a script that is meant to be run by non-technical users. The script sets up a new EC2 instance and programmatically runs several commands on that instance to set up a http server. As far as I know, there is not a good way to automatically generate ssh keypairs, and I dont want to have to manually manage multiple ssh keypairs for every ec2 instance that is deployed.

Comment: I'm not sure what security you're looking for but if you've got an HTTP server then you could use that to upload.  You'd have to have some code running with it or behind it but it would work with perhaps a `curl` command.  Boto3 is just using the underlying AWS APIs and it's not going to work around the ssh requirements.

Comment: I would push the file(s) to a private S3 bucket first, and then run `aws s3 cp` commands on the EC2 server via SSM.

Comment: @stdunbar well the files for the server are what I want to upload! I specifically wanted to use SSM to upload the py files and the requirements and so on, instead of trying to clone from github remotely (would have to go through an additional layer of auth)

Comment: I misunderstood - thought it was for after the server was up.  @MarkB has likely the best suggestion then.  Use either SSM or give the instance an IAM role and `aws s3 cp` them from the bucket as part of your user data setup of the EC2.

Comment: "The script sets up a new EC2 instance and programmatically runs several commands on that instance to set up a http server. " I just saw this part. Why not just pass the commands as `user-data` instead of using SSM?

Comment: When you say "files" (to upload), what order of size are you thinking? Kilobytes, megabytes, bigger?

Comment: @MarkB I thought about going the user data route. It's not a bad idea, but to give some more context we manage our infra with terraform and the actual provisioning the instance is done more or less manually. I'm also not sure that those commands will help get a file off a local disk onto the ec2 instance

Comment: @Erwin I'm uploading a python file and requirements.txt file (both kb) as well as a faiss index file (which can be up to ten mb). I was curious if send_command had a size limit because in theory I could just send the file as part of the send_command, but my guess is 10mb is pushing it

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html -- Yeah there are limits to what you can send (there always are!) :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but I ended up going with @MarkB's suggestion to create an S3 file as an intermediary and upload/download from there.

Comment: so echo didn't work for you SSM